# change size of widget one someone else's webpage

Tags: css, widget, html

I use the webpage https://pair-code.github.io/facets/ regularly and I would like the Dive widget window to stretch out to the total size of the screen where it is displayed.

Is there a way, beyond installing a local copy of the webpage, to achieve this so that I can see a bigger widget (I hope this is the right terminology) on the loaded website on my browser?

Comment: The *usual* way to do something like this would be to use custom styles or a userscript (or, manually, with the console / developer tools), but because the elements in question are a `canvas` and `svg`s being changed with JS, I'm not sure if it's interactable enough.

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, I guess the only solution is for me to install locally and see if I can change it myself.